# ReactJS + Express.js + React-Bootstrap: onClick handler for Bootstrap button not working

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I just started learning ReactJS and I can't seem to get the onClick handler to work.

I followed the Express.js application generator tutorial and ended up with the following code.

Can somebody please tell me what's wrong?

```js
//app.js file

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

// routes
var launch = require('./routes/launch');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// attach url to routes
app.use('/', launch);
```

```js
//launch.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('launch', {});
});

module.exports = router;
```

```js
//launch.jsx code

var React = require('react');
var DefaultLayout = require('./layouts/default');

// bootstrap
import {Button, Grid, Row, Col, Clearfix, Image, FormGroup, InputGroup, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';

var LaunchView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <FormGroup>
      <InputGroup>
      <FormControl id="launch-email" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <InputGroup.Button>
      <Button id="launch-submit" className="button-green" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </InputGroup.Button>
      </InputGroup>
      </FormGroup>
    );
  },
  handleSubmit: function(){
    alert("woot");
  }
});

module.exports = LaunchView;
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/erichardson30/pen/aZmQBm this works fine for me. What issue are you having?

Comment: @erichardson30 i'm not using React.render();. ExpressJs uses routes. I have just added my route file in my question.

Comment: Is your component being rendered when you navigate to the route?

Comment: @erichardson30 yes it is being rendered but the onClick handler is not being attached. btw i am also using react-bootstrap

Comment: using express for routing and react-bootstrap shouldn't be making the difference. it's still rendering JSX to a page and attaching an onClick handler to it. I'm not seeing an issue and can't really troubleshoot anymore without some sort of example

Answer (score 0):

doesn't support attaching events on the client-side or doing client-side updates afterwards.
https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

You can implemented a small "hack" and insert a script file which explicitly sets element's onclick behavior. Keep in mind that DOM has to be loaded in order to attach events.

```
let myElement = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0]; 
myElement.addEventListener('click', () => {myElement.style.display = 'none';});
```

It's not elegant, but it works.